# Batch-Script for formatting XML-files | Search for Strings and comment them out

Tags: xml, string, batch-file, format

So I have a XML-File, which isn't formatted, meaning it only has one line. The problem I have is, I want to delete two lines or comment them out.

Is there a way to format the XML-file using a batch-script, so if i have:

```
<xml><tag><othertag></othertag></tag></xml>
```

the output would be

```
<xml>
     <tag>
          <othertag>
          </othertag>
     </tag>
</xml>
```

Alternatively, how can I replace/add Strings, when I only  have a pattern, and can't use findstr /v, because I only have one line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you limited to batch as a scripting language ?

Comment: Use xsl and an identity transform with indenting.

Comment: The thing is, I dont need to do this for only one file. I need to do this for many subdirectories. And I have not much knowledge about xsl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable with spaces
set "spaces= "
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do set "spaces=!spaces!!spaces!"

rem Read the line
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do set "line=%%a"

set level=0
:nextTag
   rem Separate first tag from line
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=<" %%a in ("!line!") do (
      set "tag=%%a"
      set "line=%%b"
   )
   rem Show first tag in one separate line
   if "%tag:~0,1%" equ "/" set /A level-=5
   echo !spaces:~0,%level%!^<!tag!
   if "%tag:~0,1%" neq "/" set /A level+=5
if defined line goto nextTag
```

Output:

```
<xml>
     <tag>
          <othertag>
          </othertag>
     </tag>
</xml>
```

Note that the maximum length of a line that can be processed this way is 8150 characters approx. Also, this solution remove any exclamation-marks from the file. Both points can be fixed, if required.

Comment: Great! On the commandline it works, only need to add, that it writes the output in a new file. The character-limitation is no problem, but they exclamation-mark would be a deal, since the files will be used for mocking, so there should be no change.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@echo off

call ::beautifyXml c:\some.xml

exit /b %errorlevel%

::::::::::::::::::
:beautifyXml
@echo off
powershell "function fx($xml, $i=2){$SW=New-Object System.IO.StringWriter;$XW=New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $SW; $XW.Formatting='indented';$XW.Indentation=$i;([xml]$xml).WriteContentTo($XW);$XW.Flush();$SW.Flush();Write-Output $SW.ToString();};FX (gc -path """%~f1""") -i 4">"%~dp1~"
move /y "%~dp1~" "%~f1" >nul 2>nul
goto :eof
```