# Using batch code to mass xml formatting?

Tags: xml, batch-file, format

I have a folder that contains 50 subfolders each one of these contains 2 xml files

```
O_DATA.xml
S_DATA.xml
```

Since they appear in one line in Notepad, I have to fix the formatting.

---

I have found from a similar question here this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable with spaces
set "spaces= "
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do set "spaces=!spaces!!spaces!"

rem Read the line
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do set "line=%%a"

set level=0
:nextTag
   rem Separate first tag from line
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=<" %%a in ("!line!") do (
      set "tag=%%a"
      set "line=%%b"
   )
   rem Show first tag in one separate line
   if "%tag:~0,1%" equ "/" set /A level-=5
   echo !spaces:~0,%level%!^<!tag!
   if "%tag:~0,1%" neq "/" set /A level+=5
if defined line goto nextTag
```

[Batch-Script for formatting XML-files | Search for Strings and comment them out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077104/batch-script-for-formatting-xml-files-search-for-strings-and-comment-them-out)

But it is not really the same thing and also I've been studying this answer but I don't know much about batch code.

So the question is how to make a batch script that will run through that folder structure and format them?

**Update**:
I tried this:

```
C:\Users\user>for /d %%X in (C:\<C:\Users\user\Desktop\qq>\*)
do (c:\<C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-
32b\bin>\tidy.exe -m -xml -config c:\<C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-
vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin>\tidycfg.ini %%X\<O_DATA>.xml)

gives: %%X was unexpected at this time.
```

and if I delete one % gives:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

the `ini` file has:

```
indent:yes
indent-attributes:yes
```

Comment: Open them in a more modern text editor first, to determine if the file is actually multiline, but using CR line endings as opposed to CRLF. _I believe that the latest update version of Notepad on Windows 10 now supports the Linux and MAC line endings too_. If there is only one line then there are hundreds of free, portable and online products which can do this for you. I'd suggest you search or research `Pretty` + `XML`, as well as the available software, I'm sure that you will find examples of commandline tools and scripts which attempts or purports to reformat XML into human readable text.

Comment: Why do you have to fix the formatting?

Comment: @Dormilich Because it is a deliverable and they want it like that.

Comment: @Compo I have searched before I post this question and found this: https://xmlwriter.net/user_tools/tidy.shtml but I don't know how to make it work in a loop in order to fix all the files in these folders because it still needs batch code.

Comment: user10190263, once you've found your tool of choice, read and understand its command line usage and try it with a few single files until you get the pattern of options as you prefer. Then all you need to do is to  enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt to find out how to iterate a set of files  and perform your command on each of those returned from the set.

Comment: I will try with this software I mentioned. Thanks!!

Comment: @Compo Check the updated question. I have done it almost. What do you think needs correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that your subfolders are all inside the `qq` directory, and you are using `tidy.exe`, also in the location provided.

From a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "FilePath=%UserProfile%\Desktop\qq"
Set "TidyPath=%UserProfile%\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin"
For /D %%A In ("%FilePath%\*") Do For %%B In ("%%A\*.xml") Do "%TidyPath%\tidy.exe" -m -xml -i "%%B"
```

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
For /D %A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\qq\*") Do For %B In ("%A\*.xml") Do "%UserProfile%\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin\tidy.exe" -m -xml -i "%B"
```

Comment: The first code works great but the second says `"C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin"`  is not recognized as an internal or external command, what could be wrong?

Comment: @user10190263, it was a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that does not need external tool installations (I'm partially using the Compo's answer):

```
@echo Off

Set "FilesPath=%UserProfile%\Desktop\qq"

for /D %%A in ("%FilesPath%\*") do (
    for %%B In ("%%A\*.xml") do (
        call ::beautifyXml "%%~fB"
    )
)


exit /b %errorlevel%

::::::::::::::::::
:beautifyXml
@echo off
powershell "function fx($xml, $i=2){$SW=New-Object System.IO.StringWriter;$XW=New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $SW; $XW.Formatting='indented';$XW.Indentation=$i;([xml]$xml).WriteContentTo($XW);$XW.Flush();$SW.Flush();Write-Output $SW.ToString();};FX (gc -path """%~f1""") -i 4">"%~dp1~"
move /y "%~dp1~" "%~f1" >nul 2>nul
goto :eof
```

It does not checks if the files have valid xml syntax which can harm their content so back-up in advance just in case.