# %%X was unexpected at this time

Tags: xml, batch-file, format

I try to make a batch script using the `tidy` software like this: But I don't know 
much about Batch scripting. Here is the code:

I tried this:

```
C:\Users\user>for /d %%X in (C:\<C:\Users\user\Desktop\qq>\*) #parent dir
do (c:\<C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-
32b\bin>\tidy.exe -m -xml -config c:\<C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-
vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin>\tidycfg.ini %%X\<O_DATA>.xml)

gives: %%X was unexpected at this time.
```

and if I delete one % gives:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

the `ini` file has:

```
indent:yes
indent-attributes:yes
```

The script attempts to format xml files that are like this:

```
main folder > subfolders that have an xml each called: O_DATA.xml
```

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and learn the correct syntax! If you type a `for` command into command prompt, you must use single `%`-signs, in a batch file they need to be doubled! Do you really have the `<`/`>` characters in your tried command line??

Comment: @aschipfl it's one now. And the `</>` are like the code. What else needs to be fixed?

Comment: `C:\<C:\` is an invalid path and filename in Windows. First learn how your OS works before trying to do things from the command line. What is contained inside the XML doesn't belong on the command line for a filename, and at the very least would need to be escaped in cases where it is being used appropriately.

Comment: Why did you start another question?  You already had one opened for this same problem!

Comment: @user10190263, I have posted a solution in the [original question you opened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51740005), this question should not have been asked whilst the same question was still live and unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to use illegal characters for your file paths.  If you really want to run this as a single line command from the cmd prompt then I believe this is what you are attempting to do.

```
for /D %X IN (C:\Users\user\Desktop\qq\*) do C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin\tidy.exe -m -xml -config C:\Users\user\Downloads\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\tidy-5.6.0-vc14-32b\bin\tidycfg.ini %X\O_DATA.xml
```

If you want to run this code inside a batch file, then you need to double the percent symbols for the FOR variable.