# How to make XML formatted using batch script tag by tag(Pretty Print)?

Tags: xml, batch-file, formatting

Suppose I am having below format in one file:

```
         `<xml><tag><othertag>ABC</othertag></tag></xml>`
```

But I need  below formatted output :

```
<xml>
 <tag>
      <othertag>ABC</othertag>
 </tag>
```

This formatted output i need it in other file.

help me with the batch script which will be able to do such formatting.

Comment: this can be done easy with xslt transformation and a script using vbscript,jscript or powershell (which are installed by default on windows) called by a batch script. Later I'll try to create a script for this.

Comment: Working with XML in batch can be very tricky, due to all the special characters encountered. Search for [xml formatter](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=AjHnW_rWApiy0PEP1YKb6AU&q=xml+formatter&oq=xml+for&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.1878.3324..5589...0.0..0.55.306.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131.ItyIANfBVic) on google and you should find plenty of free software that can convert between deflated and pretty formatted forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using batch code to mass xml formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740005/using-batch-code-to-mass-xml-formatting)

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

try this (it does not check if the xml has valid syntax):

```
call ::beautifyXml "c:\some.xml"
call ::beautifyXml "c:\some.xml" > "c:\new.xml"

exit /b %errorlevel%


:beautifyXml
powershell "function fx($xml, $i=2){$SW=New-Object System.IO.StringWriter;$XW=New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $SW; $XW.Formatting='indented';$XW.Indentation=$i;([xml]$xml).WriteContentTo($XW);$XW.Flush();$SW.Flush();Write-Output $SW.ToString();};FX (gc -path """%~f1""") -i 4"
goto :eof
```

if you the new file looks ok you can add additional move command to replace the old one.

Comment: With XML files mostly encoded in UTF8 I'd prefer to write to file in the powershell part probaply with an -Encoding parameter.

Comment: @LotPings - Good point. Later (if I have the time) I'll try to edit the script.

Answer (score 0):

A XML file should not be processed via a Batch file. However, *this particular example* give me the opportunity to get some fun with a Batch file, and it works! **`;)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=2 delims=`" %%a in (input.txt) do set "format=%%a"

for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set NL=%%a^
% Don't remove %
% these lines  %
set "SP=    "
set "format=%format:></=>^!NL^!^!SP:~0,-8^!" ^& set "SP=^!SP:~0,-4^!" ^& set /P "=</%"
< NUL (set /P "=%format:><=>!NL!!SP!" & set "SP=    !SP!" & set /P "=<%" & echo/) > output.txt
```

Output:

```
<xml>
    <tag>
        <othertag>ABC</othertag>
    </tag>
</xml>
```

For a description on the method used, see [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429).

Comment: HI Aacini, you have given an excellent  solution !!  , please can you give a fix for handling more than  8150 characters in your solution over this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077104/batch-script-for-formatting-xml-files-search-for-strings-and-comment-them-out